# IE 11 Magento 2.1.15 Braintree - Place Order Button is not working

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, place-order, braintree, internet-explorer

In Internet Explorer 11, when **Braintree** Payment Method is chosen `Place Order` button is not working. The Magento version is 2.1.15. I am using One Step Checkout. Place Order is not working fine in default one-page checkout too. The error does occur only in IE 11 whereas in Edge and other browsers it is working normally.

Found few errors in the browser console

> SCRIPT5: Access is Denied

https://prnt.sc/n3owdv

Few scripts from https://assets.braintreegateway.com are being blocked by the browser. Tried adding the link to trusted sites and did more configuration changes. Although the script is being blocked.

How to resolve this error? Any help is needful.